# How to count number of macro execution?

Tags: c++

I have two macros that declares class properties:

```
DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_LONG(name)
DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_STRING(name)
```

I want to count number of calls of this macros inside of my class and init

```
static const size_t paramsCount
```

with that number like this:

```
class MyClass {
...

    DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_LONG(param1)
    DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_STRING(param2)
    DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_STRING(param3)
    DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_LONG(param4)

    static const size_t paramsCount = PARAMS_COUNT; // 4 in this case

...
};
```

Is this ever possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can at least count number of lines in the following way:

```
class MyClass
{
    static const int line_1 = __LINE__;
    DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_LONG(param1)
    DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_STRING(param2)
    DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_STRING(param3)
    DECLARE_QUERY_PARAM_LONG(param4)
    static const int line_2 = __LINE__;
    static const int macro_calls = line_2 - line_1 - 1;

public:
    MyClass()
    {
        cout << macro_calls << endl;
    }
};
```

<strike>But I think you'll need C++11 to do that. And</strike> You cannot have empty lines within those two `__LINE__`s. Otherwise, you'll have to count those empty lines as well.

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. As far as I understood the question, he wants to count number of a certain macro expansions in all files.

Comment: C++98 should be able to handle this.

Comment: @VladimirJovic: i agree i'm slightly confused. my solution will work in only one scenario mentioned as an example by OP.

Comment: @fefe: i knew that member variables can be initialized at the place of declaration inside a class only in c++11.

Comment: @Donotalo I might have misunderstood the question :/

Comment: @Donotalo That also can be done in C++98 when the variable is a `static const` and has integral type.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need. Empty lines restriction is acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

There would be a solution, rather complicated:

1. All your parameters will have a fixed name (say *param*)
2. You need to create one header file per type
3. You shall need boost

So here is the header creation file:

```
// file declare_int.h

#include BOOST_PP_UPDATE_COUNTER()

int stringize(param,BOOST_PP_COUNTER) ;
```

and the class file:

```
//file declare_auto.cpp
#include <boost/preprocessor/slot/counter.hpp>

#define _stringize(a,b) a##b
#define stringize(a,b) _stringize(a,b)

// reset counter
#if defined(BOOST_PP_COUNTER)
#undef BOOST_PP_COUNTER
#endif

class A {
public:

#include "declare_int.h"
#include "declare_int.h"
#include "declare_int.h"
#include "declare_int.h"

static const int nbParams = BOOST_PP_COUNTER ;
};
```

and finally the output of:

> g++ -E -P -c declare_auto.cpp -IPATH_TO_BOOST

is

```
class A {
public:
int param1 ;
int param2 ;
int param3 ;
int param4 ;
static const int nbParams = 4 ;
};
```

Comment: Note that the `#include <boost/preprocessor/slot/counter.hpp>` will reset the `BOOST_PP_COUNTER` for you so you should not `#undef` it. Plus, I think it should be `#undef` and then set back to `0` or the macros may get lost.

Answer (score 2):

As such no.

What you are asking for would require some form of introspection, which is not natively supported by C++.

You can improve the macro though, if you had:

```
DECLARE_QUERY_PARAMS(((LONG  , param1))
                     ((STRING, param2))
                     ((STRING, param3))
                     ((LONG  , param4)))
```

then you could do what you want.

You can have a look at Boost.Preprocessor to learn how to obfuscate your sources this way.

*Note: this uses a Sequence, in boost parlance.*

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a standard way to do this, but the DevStudio compiler has this preprocessor macro:

> __COUNTER__
>
> Expands to an integer starting with 0 and incrementing by 1 every time it is used in a compiland. __COUNTER__ remembers its state when using precompiled headers. If the last __COUNTER__ value was 4 after building a precompiled header (PCH), it will start with 5 on each PCH use.
>
> __COUNTER__ lets you generate unique variable names. You can use token pasting with a prefix to make a unique name. For example:

```
// pre_mac_counter.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define FUNC2(x,y) x##y 
#define FUNC1(x,y) FUNC2(x,y)
#define FUNC(x) FUNC1(x,__COUNTER__)

int FUNC(my_unique_prefix);
int FUNC(my_unique_prefix);
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Macro's don't respect scope at all, and don't understand that they're inside a class.

Comment: You could pass the class name to the macro to get around that particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

No. Macros aren't executed, they're expanded and not even by compiler, but by preprocessor.